# How to set the default debug page in MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

In MVC 1 in VS2008, you could right click the Default.aspx page and set as default page, then hit debug and land on the home view (even though Default.aspx was something else).  In MVC2, Default.aspx isn't there, so how do you set the default document to be the home index default view?

I know it is set this way by default, but if you are stupid like me, you already right clicked something and incorrectly set it as the default page.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project properties, you can set it there.  You shouldn't refer to the startup page as default.aspx; I believe it's empty in my project as the default.  This is because of the URL rewriting feature.

Comment: Great!  Like you suggested, I found it under project properties, under Web-> Start Action.